# Letting another widget handle your events in Qt

Tags: qt, events

I have a `QSpinBox` in a `QMainWindow` holding a value. Natively the spinbox, well ... spins on `QWheelEvent` if focused. I would like to expand the scrolling of the value in the spinbox to be applied invariantly of focus within the window.
The spinbox manages a value that dictates behavior to the whole context of the window live.

I am trying to divert the scroll event to the spinbox to be handled by the latter to implement this instead of handling a custom value somewhere and to synchronize it with the spinbox manually.
But I am failing. I have an EventFilter in the window that can intercept the event in the window invariantly of focus, but the `wheelEvent` method in the spinbox is protected so I cannot call it from there.

I do not want to just make a custom spinbox for this if I can help it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event filter, do not call the protected `spinBox->wheelEvent(wheelEvent)`. You can instead pass the event to the spin box using static function `QCoreApplication::sendEvent(spinBox, wheelEvent)`.

Of course, seeing your code would help to show more concrete solution. Especially you should make sure that your event filter does not intercept this re-sent event again, creating an infinite loop...

Comment: sadly the `event` method is reimplemented as protected in `QSpinBox`, so I cannot call it either. I will check out the latter method.

Comment: which seems to work without issue !

Comment: OK, you are right. `event()` is public in base class `QObject` but is reimplemented as protected in derived classes, e.g. `QSpinBox`. I will update my answer accordingly so that it does not confuse others. Thanks for correction.